# tidyverse package installing issue in docker

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, tidyverse

I am new to containerization and docker. I want to run my R script from docker localy. After some research I specified dockerfile (below), however, when I run docker image an error occurs. The issue is following "Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse". Since I run docker image building in CMD I see process of library instalation, however, package probably installs somewhere outside docker.

I use following dockerfile to build image:

```
FROM r-base:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev


RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyverse', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies=TRUE)"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('rvest', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies=TRUE)"

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

CMD ["Rscript", "test.R"]
```

My OS is Windows 10

I want to run R script from docker, but R do not see instaled packages.

Comment: `there is no package` suggests to me that your docker container during build does not have un-proxied internet access. However, try `https://` instead of `http://` in case that has any effect (firewalls, corporate policies, etc).

Comment: As an alternative (if _building_ a custom docker image is not your real need), you could consider using the (huge) rocker/tidyverse image, see https://rocker-project.org/images/versioned/rstudio.html.

Comment: Could you briefly describe how to run my script from rocker's image? I dont even know which one to choose: rstudio or tidyverse.

Comment: Do you not see any errors when you build your image? I would guess that the tidyverse package installation fails due to missing system requirements. My guess is you'll have to run `apt-get install` for a few more packages to get it to work. Typically they tell you the name of the required packages in the error message output.

Comment: Zero errors during image building, issue appears only when i try to run it "Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’ Execution halted". I also tried to fix my dockerfile within ChatGPT but it also did work.

Comment: @andrewandrew, two ways: (1) change `FROM r-base:latest` to `FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest` (or whatever), remove the package-installation steps, keeping `COPY` and `CMD`; (2) use the raw image, and use volume mount to bring a local (non-docker) directory or files into the container when running it.

Comment: Three ways:  use `FROM rocker/r2u:jammy` and use `RUN install.r tidyverse rvest`.  Small and fast and reliable _and from binaries_ so much easier -- see https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/ for more.